# How to make @Around advice (Spring AOP) on RestController GET Method execute after constraint validation in the GET method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I want constraint validation in the method to happen before around advice aspect execution, but I see the opposite happening. The aspect is triggered without validation.

I have the following RestController class:

```java
package com.pkg;

@RestController
@Validated
public class RestController {
  @GetMapping("/v1/{id}")
  public Object getIDInformation(
    @PathVariable("id")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$", message = "Non numeric id")
    @Size(min = 9, max = 10, message = "Invalid id")
      String id,
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
    SomeClass someObject
  )
  {
    return service.getIDInformation(Long.parseLong(id), someObject);
  }
}
```

Then I have the following around aspect advice in a different class:

```java
@Around(
  "execution(* com.pkg.RestController.getIDInformation(..)) && " +
  "args(id,httpRequest,..)"
)
public Object aspectMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String id, HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
  throws Throwable
{
  SomeClass someObject = changedValue;
  Object[] targetMethodArgs = pjp.getArgs();

  if (!valid(id)) {
    //throw Exception
  }
  else {
    // Make use of HttpServletRequest httpRequest (not shown here) to modify
    // SomeClass someObject argument in the target method
    for (int i = 0; i < targetMethodArgs.length; i++) {
      if (targetMethodArgs[i] instanceof SomeClass) {
        targetMethodArgs[i] = someObject;
      }
    }
  }

  return pjp.proceed(targetMethodArgs);
}
```

If a request is made to GET handler method, the constraint validation for id path variable has to occur first before the around advice can execute. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: So you want your Advice to be executed/triggered after a constraint validation occurs ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: When the request reaches the controller method, the validations for the method parameters have to happen first. such that the constraint violation exception is thrown in the response, if there are any violations, before going to the aspect logic.

Comment: Is @AfterThrowing advice is not what you're searching for?

Comment: I suspect then, the advice will not execute if there were no constraint violations, in which case there will be no constraint violation exception. Also, I need around advice to modify the arguments for the controller method. It is very tricky. I'm not sure why validation doesn't occur first.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Are you forced to make use of Advices? Because it's seems like it's overkill.

Comment: I want to intercept the id (path variable in the GET method) from the HTTP request and check authorization for it, before the GET method logic executes.  I could probably use Spring boot's HandlerInterceptor, but I feel I will run into the same problem again. I'm not forced to use aspects, but in this case, I think it doesn't matter if I use interceptors or aspects.

Comment: You could try to build your own custom validation annotation, then you could apply that annotation like `@Pattern(..)`. For more info see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: You are right, but the validation annotations I need like @Pattern, is already available out of the box.

Comment: Yes but you create one for yourselves and combine them like `@Pattern @MyValidatior String id`

Comment: You are saying, then the validation will happen first before the advice execution? With custom validation annotations?

Comment: No no, I say don't use advices, but create your own annotation to do what you want to do with you aspect.

Comment: That's great advice. But I'm making use of the HttpServletRequest httpRequest from the controller in the advice. In the annotation, I could probably replace it with: 

HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

Will it be thread safe, then?

Comment: Also edited the question to show correctly, why I need to use advice. So a solution to the original problem is absolutely needed :(

Comment: I think HTTP filter is the thing to use here, not aspect-oriented programming.  Filters have been around longer.  They're intended for use with HTTP.

Comment: You are right. I should use Filter.

Comment: @Barani, I wrote an extensive answer 5 days ago. I think it would be polite to react to it - much appreciated.

Comment: @kriegaex, I apologise. I had the upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preface

I am not a Spring user, so I cannot tell you

- if there is any way to influence the order of advisor application for any advised bean in a generic, non-invasive way,
- where exactly Spring creates the list of advisors associated with an advised bean while wiring the application.

What I did find out, however, is that once the list of advisors for an advised bean has been set, it is simply applied in the order of elements in the list. You can influence aspect precedence via `@Order` or implementing `@Ordered`, but I have no idea if that approach can somehow be applied to method validation advisors.

#### Proof of concept, version 1

Because I was curious, I created a proof-of-concept, hacky workaround. Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) replicating your original situation:

**Service, controller and helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

public class SomeClass {
  private final String suffix;

  public SomeClass(String suffix) {
    this.suffix = suffix;
  }

  public String getSuffix() {
    return suffix;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyService {
  public String getIDInformation(long id, SomeClass someObject) {
    return id + "-" + someObject.getSuffix();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@RestController
@Validated
public class MyRestController {
  @Autowired
  MyService service;

  @GetMapping("/v1/{id}")
  public Object getIDInformation(
    @PathVariable("id")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$", message = "Non-numeric ID ${validatedValue}")
    @Size(min = 9, max = 10, message = "ID ${validatedValue} must be {min}-{max} numbers long")
      String id,
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
    SomeClass someObject
  )
  {
    return service.getIDInformation(Long.parseLong(id), someObject);
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

My dummy for the missing `valid(String id)` method in your example simply returns `true` if the ID contains a `'0'` character.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyRestControllerAspect {
  @Around(
    "execution(* de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(..)) && " +
    "args(id, httpRequest, ..)"
  )
  public Object aspectMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String id, HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
    throws Throwable
  {
    System.out.println(pjp + " -> " + id);
    SomeClass changedValue = new SomeClass("ASPECT");
    SomeClass someObject = changedValue;
    Object[] targetMethodArgs = pjp.getArgs();

    if (!valid(id)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid ID " + id);
    }
    else {
      // Make use of HttpServletRequest httpRequest (not shown here) to modify
      // SomeClass someObject argument in the target method
      for (int i = 0; i < targetMethodArgs.length; i++) {
        if (targetMethodArgs[i] instanceof SomeClass) {
          targetMethodArgs[i] = someObject;
        }
      }
    }

    return pjp.proceed(targetMethodArgs);
  }

  private boolean valid(String id) {
    return id.contains("0");
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    MyRestController restController = appContext.getBean(MyRestController.class);
    //reorderAdvisorsMethodValidationFirst(restController);

    printIDInfo(restController, "1234567890", "Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')");
    printIDInfo(restController, "123456789", "Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')");
    printIDInfo(restController, "123", "Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')");
    printIDInfo(restController, "250", "Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')");
    printIDInfo(restController, "x", "Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')");
    printIDInfo(restController, "A0", "Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')");
  }

  private static void printIDInfo(MyRestController restController, String id, String infoMessage) {
    try {
      System.out.println(infoMessage);
      System.out.println("ID info: " + restController.getIDInformation(id, null, new SomeClass("ABC")));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("----------");
  }

  public static void reorderAdvisorsMethodValidationFirst(Object targetBean) {
    if (!(targetBean instanceof Advised))
      return;
    Advised advisedBean = (Advised) targetBean;
    Arrays.stream(advisedBean.getAdvisors())
      .filter(advisor -> !(advisor.getAdvice() instanceof MethodValidationInterceptor))
      .forEach(advisor -> {
        advisedBean.removeAdvisor(advisor);
        advisedBean.addAdvisor(advisor);
      });
  }
}
```

Please note the one helper method call I commented out. When running the application like this, the console log says:

```
Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> 1234567890
ID info: 1234567890-ASPECT
----------
Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> 123456789
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ID 123456789
----------
Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> 123
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ID 123
----------
Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> 250
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getIDInformation.id: ID 250 must be 9-10 numbers long
----------
Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> x
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ID x
----------
Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> A0
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getIDInformation.id: Non-numeric ID A0, getIDInformation.id: ID A0 must be 9-10 numbers long
```

As you can see from the logged `execution` joinpoints and ensuing `IllegalArgumentException`s, the aspect kicks in before method argument validation, just as you described.

Now, let us uncomment (i.e. activate)

```java
reorderAdvisorsMethodValidationFirst(restController);
```

What the method does, is

- to check if the target object is an advised Spring bean,
- if so, reorder the list of advisors by simply

  - temporarily removing each advisor which does not have a `MethodValidationInterceptor` advice
  - and then immediately appending it to the end of the list again.

The effect is that now the method validation interceptors take precedence over other advice types for the target bean. The console log consequently changes to:

```
Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> 1234567890
ID info: 1234567890-ASPECT
----------
Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')
execution(Object de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717.MyRestController.getIDInformation(String,HttpServletRequest,SomeClass)) -> 123456789
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ID 123456789
----------
Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getIDInformation.id: ID 123 must be 9-10 numbers long
----------
Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getIDInformation.id: ID 250 must be 9-10 numbers long
----------
Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getIDInformation.id: Non-numeric ID x, getIDInformation.id: ID x must be 9-10 numbers long
----------
Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getIDInformation.id: ID A0 must be 9-10 numbers long, getIDInformation.id: Non-numeric ID A0
```

See? Now the aspect only kicks in in the first two cases, after method parameter validation has been passed successfully.

Some Spring AOP internals:

- Method `CglibAopProxy.DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept` calls `this.advised.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(method, targetClass)`.
- `this.advised` is of type `AdvisedSupport`, which is a public type, but unfortunately `CglibAopProxy.DynamicAdvisedInterceptor` is a private static inner class of `CglibAopProxy` and only used internally.
- So there is no good way to get hold of the `AdvisedSupport` instance and e.g. call its `setAdvisorChainFactory` method. If that was possible, you could just inject a factory returning a list of advisors in an order different from the default one (a `DefaultAdvisorChainFactory`).

Maybe some Spring pros here know of a canonical way to influence the internal advisor chain order by configuring Spring in order to wire the application the way you want it to, but I really do not know. I am just an AOP (mostly AspectJ) expert who sometimes looks into more specific Spring AOP questions.

#### Proof of concept, version 2

OK, I refactored the original solution into something more generic, using a `BeanPostProcessor`. The post-processor will

- be called automatically for each Spring instantiated bean,
- check if the created bean is `Advised` (i.e. is a Spring proxy with advisors),
- filter for advised bean classes with `@Validated` annotations,
- re-order the advisors like in my original solution.

The advantage is that there is no more need to manually fetch bean instances from the application context and call `reorderAdvisorsMethodValidationFirst(..)` on them one by one. Spring takes care of post-processing each bean, which is how it is supposed to be. Sorry for coming up with this solution only in iteration #2, but like I said, I am a Spring noob.

**Updated, simplified driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {
  private static MyRestController restController;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    restController = appContext.getBean(MyRestController.class);
    printIDInfo("1234567890", "Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')");
    printIDInfo("123456789", "Valid @Pattern, valid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')");
    printIDInfo("123", "Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')");
    printIDInfo("250", "Valid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')");
    printIDInfo("x", "Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, invalid for aspect (does not contain '0')");
    printIDInfo("A0", "Invalid @Pattern, invalid @Size, valid for aspect (contains '0')");
  }

  private static void printIDInfo(String id, String infoMessage) {
    try {
      System.out.println(infoMessage);
      System.out.println("ID info: " + restController.getIDInformation(id, null, new SomeClass("ABC")));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("----------");
  }

}
```

**Bean post-processor:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q71219717;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
public class MethodValidationFirstBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof Advised) {
      Advised advisedBean = (Advised) bean;
      if (advisedBean.getTargetSource().getTargetClass().isAnnotationPresent(Validated.class)) {
        System.out.println("Reordering advisors to \"method validation first\" for bean " + beanName);
        reorderAdvisorsMethodValidationFirst(advisedBean);
      }
    }
    return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
  }

  public void reorderAdvisorsMethodValidationFirst(Advised advisedBean) {
    Arrays.stream(advisedBean.getAdvisors())
      .filter(advisor -> !(advisor.getAdvice() instanceof MethodValidationInterceptor))
      .forEach(advisor -> {
        advisedBean.removeAdvisor(advisor);
        advisedBean.addAdvisor(advisor);
      });
  }
}
```

The console logs with and without the active post-processor remain the same as in the original solution.

Comment: **Update:** I added an improved, much more generic solution using a bean post-processor. See section "Proof of concept, version 2". I think this is something you might be able to live with in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the well-researched answer. I accepted it.